# SWIFT iterating through structures - issue

Tags: arrays, swift

Im trying to iterate thorough and array of structures using generics and I keep getting this error. **Value of type [T] has no member 'printMessage'**

My 2nd questions is - What message would print? The statement in the Foo protocol extension or the statement in the struct instance?

Not sure what the issue is.. and its driving me insane!

```
protocol Foo {

    func printMessage()
}


extension Foo {

    func printMessage() {
        print("Hello")
    }
    
}

struct test: Foo {

    func printMessage() {
        print("Goodbye")
    }
    
}



func MessagePrinter<T: Foo>(for message: [T]) {
    
    for message in [message] {
        message.printMessage()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrapping an array in another array here:

```
func MessagePrinter<T: Foo>(for messages: [T]) {
    for message in [messages] {
        message.printMessage()
    }
}
```

(I've renamed your function argument from `message` to `messages` to make it clearer.)

When you write `[messages]` you end up with an array containing another array containing `T`, so the type is `[[T]]`. The single element `message` thus has type `[T]`, and an array has no method `printMessage`.

What you want is this:

```
func MessagePrinter<T: Foo>(for messages: [T]) {
    for message in messages {
        message.printMessage()
    }
}
```

As for what's printed when you execute it: that depends on what elements you feed it. If the elements implement `printMessage` those methods are called (e.g. "Goodbye"). Otherwise the default implementation you have provided for the protocol is called ("Hello").

Comment: Thank you. I found that you have to delete the func declaration in the protocol, and have the default func only in the protocol extension for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

For more clarity name the array in plural form and and the element in singular form.

And the square brackets in the `for` loop are wrong, the parameter is already an array

```
func messagePrinter<T: Foo>(for messages: [T]) {
    
    for message in messages {
        message.printMessage()
    } 
}
```

And please name functions always with starting lowercase letter.

The method in the protocol extension is called unless the method is implemented.

---

But consider that `T` is a single concrete type at runtime, you cannot call the method on a heterogenous `Foo` array like this

```
let messages : [Foo] = [Test()]
messagePrinter(for: messages)
```

You will get the error

> Protocol 'Foo' as a type cannot conform to the protocol itself

To be able to call the method on an heterogenous array whose elements conform to `Foo` you have to declare

```
func messagePrinter(for messages: [Foo]) { ...
```

Comment: Thank the heavens! Some of the proper naming was just my frustration in writing out this question. It was the bracket syntax that was holding me up. Thank you!!!